# LayarPlayer - LPAugmentedRealityViewController build problem on iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, augmented-reality

I´m trying to get the LayarPlayer SDK to work but i im stuck. I´ll keep getting this warning no matter what i do. I have followed there "guide" but it doesnt help. Anyone here who can help?

`"_OBJC_CLASS_$_LPAugmentedRealityViewController", referenced from:`

`objc-class-ref-to-LPAugmentedRealityViewController in FirstViewController.o`

`ld: symbol(s) not found`

`collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you need to link to the binary library. In Xcode go "Groups & Files" (left panel in the default layout). Then right click on Add Existing Frameworks->Add Other ... locate and select liblayarplayer.a in the "Release" directory.

Comment: When i add the files it says:
ld: warning: in /Developer/ExtraLibaries/LayarPlayer SDK 11820/Debug/liblayarplayer.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Comment: Here is the project:
[LayarPlayer Project](http://www.speedyshare.com/files/26918524/LayarPlayer.zip)

Comment: Are you compiling for the Simulator? That will not work since the camera apis used by layar are not available in the simulator. Try compiling and running on the Device.

Comment: Also, the binary libraries in the Layar API are for ARM achitecture. That is why you see that warning.

Comment: The problem disappeared when i compile and run it on my Device, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not accurately added their library, or you might not be importing the appropriate files accordingly using #import.

Please post the code of your FirstViewContoller.m

Comment: I think the error shows up, as you have not added imported LPAugmentedRealityViewController in any of those files. try using `# import "LPAugmentedRealityViewController.h"

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work. I have maybe missed something when i followed their documentation, but i have tried several times.
Layar´s documentation:
[documentation](http://layar.pbworks.com/w/page/35051901/Layar-Player-on-IPhone)